# How do I remove hardcoded subtitles?

Tags: video, subtitles

I have a video. There are hardcoded subtitles (chinese) in this video but I want to add my own english subtitles.

How do I remove them?

Is it possible to put a black rectangle over the subtitles and add mine over the top?

Comment: Search "mkvtoolnix" on google